# sapply combined with ur.df

Tags: r, time-series, sapply

I have a multivariate time series (xts) object, on which I would like use the ur.df function.

```
data <- read.zoo("file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", format="%d-%m-%y")
test <- sapply(data, ur.df)
```

This part works without any problems, and the following code also works without any problems.

```
test2 <- ur.df(data, lags=10, type='trend')
```

However, if I want to use the following code, there will be an error (first one results in "y is missing", whereas second one results in "y is not a vector").

```
test3 <- sapply(data, ur.df(lags=10, type='trend')
test4 <-sapply(data, ur.df(data, lags=10, type='trend')
```

So basically I am unable to enter any non-default settings for the function I am (s)applying to my dataset. Is there any convenient way to make this work?

Comment: `sapply(data, ur.df, lags=10, type='trend')`

Comment: great, that solved my problem! would you mind posting it as an answer so i can approve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close out the question so it won't appear unanswered, i'll repost @shadow's answer

```
sapply(data, ur.df, lags=10, type='trend')
```